# Invariant Violation: View config not found for name div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to render  in react-native project. But simulator shows me the error:
Invariant Violation: `View config` not found for name div
What is the matter?
Is there a solution for rendering `<div>` in react-native?

Code sample:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>123</div>
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`<div>` is an invalid React Native `Component`

You should use [React Native Basic Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html#basic-components)

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>123</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

`View` is a container that supports layout with flexbox, style, some touch handling, and access controls. Whereas `<Text>` can be used in order to display any text.

Answer (score 3):

the [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html) does not list HTML elements as valid view components.  There is no view config for `<div>` because `<div>` is not a React Native component.